# Python 3.x: applying regular expressions (re) to only a substring of a larger string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to figure out how to apply regex to a substring. See below:

```
import re

string = 'useless_text AAA <>one<><>two<><>three<> BBB <>four<><>five<>'

pattern = re.compile('AAA <>(.*?)<> BBB')

print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

What it returns:

```
['one<><>two<><>three']
```

What I want it to return:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

In other words, I don't care about anything before AAA and I don't want the regex to return 'four' and 'five' after BBB.

Is there any way to format this regex **without** having to first create a new string that excludes 'AAA' and everything before it, and 'BBB' and everything after it, and then running the regex on that new string?

Thanks!

Comment: `[_.split('<><>') for _ in re.findall(pattern, string)]`

Comment: @PauloScardine Thanks for the response but I'm primarily interested to know if there is a best way to do this with the re function itself. I'll change my post slightly to underscore that for the large strings I'm working with, methods like split() won't help me too much. Thanks!

Comment: Because `AAA` and `BBB` only appear once in the whole string, there can be only one complete match. Either use split as suggested by Paulo Scardine or extract the substring using a similar pattern to your current pattern and then use re.findall on that to get a list of the further substrings. i.e. the 2nd regex could be `pattern2 = re.compile('>([^<>]*)<')`

Comment: Even if there is a regex that can do it in one pass, it will be a hell of a complex and unreadable one. Sometimes it is best to do two simple steps than a single step that is hard to maintain. The second step does not have to be a split, it may be a second regex.

Comment: Ok thank you both very much! The second regex was my initial approach. I was just curious if it was possible to eliminate the extra step but as a keep playing with it, I think I agree with you in that it would overcomplicate things. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This :

```
import re

string = 'useless_text AAA <>one<><>two<><>three<> BBB <>four<><>five<>'

pattern = re.compile('AAA (<>.*?<>) BBB')
pattern2 = re.compile('<>([^<>]*)<>')

print(re.findall(pattern2, re.search(pattern, string).group(1)))
```

Will return :

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```